# Google Maps Platform サービスのAPI keyは無料で利用できる？

Tags: google-api

Google Maps Platform サービスというのがありますがまずAPIkeyの使用は無料でしょうか？(このサービスに加入しなくても)APIkeyの使用は制限はありますか？またGoogle Maps Platform サービスには無料版がありますか？

Comment: https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/ こちらのページは見ましたか？見てもわからなかったと言うことですか？

Comment: 見た感じ有料っぽいですね。Google Maps Platformはいったん置いといて私はGitHubからSuperAGIをパソコン内に導入しようといてるのですがその際にAPIkeyを使うんですよ。だからそのAPIkeyは無料か有料か知りたいです。

Comment: リンク先をみて質問の答えがわかったのであれば、わかった内容のを自分で回答してください。わからなかった場合は、「見た感じ有料っぽいですね。」などと曖昧にせずに、「わからなかった」と明確にコメントするか、質問に追記してください。その時、具体的にどういうところがわからなかったのか記載があるとより的確な回答を得られる可能性が高くなります。

Comment: SuperAGIについては別の質問ですよね？スタック・オーバーフローは一つの投稿で一つの質問のみをすることを推奨しています。SuperAGIについて聞きたい場合は、新たに質問を投稿してください。

Comment: いえ、superAGIについてはAPIkeyを調べることになった経路を言っておくべきかなと思い補足しただけです。

Comment: Google Maps Platformについてよくわからなかった点は無料トライアルがまずどれくらい続きまた期限が切れたらAPIkeyが使えなくなるかもしくは有料版になり請求されるのかってとこですね。

Answer (score 3):

https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

Google Maps Platformの料金については上記に全て書いていますが、なるべく噛み砕いてで説明します。

Google Maps Platformは無料枠有り従量課金の1プランです(別途エンタープライズ向けや非営利団体向けのディスカウントがありますが、ここでは言及しません)。「無料プラン」や「有料プラン」といった金額によってわかれるプランは無く、また、「有料プランの無料体験」のようなものもありません。選べるプランは無料枠有り従量課金の1プランのみです。以下、このプランについて解説します。

このプランではAPIの呼び出し1回毎に課金されます。1回あたりの料金はAPIによって異なり、また、大量アクセスは割引もあります。中にはどれだけ使っても無料というAPIもあります。どのAPIがどれぐらいでいくらになるのかは、最初のURLのところでシミュレーションができるので、使う予定のAPIの月あたりの回数入れて確認してみてください。

月単位で、実際に呼び出されたAPIの回数に応じた料金の合計で、全体料金が決まります。しかし、この金額全てが請求されるわけではありません。月あたり200米ドルまでは無料枠があり、200米ドルを超える金額だけが登録したクレジットカードに請求されます。料金が200米ドル以内であれば、その月は請求されません。

ということで、 **「無料版」はありません** が、APIの呼び出し回数が少ない(または、無料で利用可能なAPIのみ使用している)場合はその月は無料になります。逆に言うと、意図せずに月あたりの回数が無料枠を越えた場合は有料になります。必ず無料のまま使いたいという場合は、[1日あたりの呼び出し回数を制限できる](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=ja#usage_cap)ようですので、そういった機能をお使いください。

Comment: 説明を読んで少し気になったことがあるのですが、まず無料版に関しては使用期限などはありますでしょうか？そしてクレジットカードの登録は必要でしょうか？

Comment: 回答にも書いたとおり、**無料版はありません**。毎月200米ドルの無料枠が与えられる従量課金であり、そういう意味では(少ないときは$0の月もある)有料版しかないと言ってもいいと思います。また、「よくある質問」にも書いていますが、必ず請求できるようにクレジットカードまたは請求先アカウント(銀行口座などを結びつけたアカウント)は必須となっているようです。

Comment: 成る程...Google Maps Platform以外にもAPIkeyを使用できるサイトでPinecornというのがありますがそれはどうでしょうか？多分Google Maps Platformよりは使えると思いますが..

Comment: 「APIキー」というのはあるサービスのAPIを利用するときに認証に使う秘密の文字列です。このAPIキーはサービス毎に異なり、そのサービスにしか使えません。Google Maps Platformのサービスにユーザー登録して取得できるAPIキーはGoogle Maps Platformにのみ使え、他のサービスには使えないと言うことです。
もしかして、一つAPIキーを取得すれば、色んなサービスに利用できると勘違いしていませんか？Google Maps PlatformのAPIキーはGoogle Maps Platform以外のサービスに使えませんよ。同じように別のサービスのAPIキーはGoogle Maps Platofrmに使えません。
もし、とにかく「APIキー」というものを取得したい**だけ**というのであれば、それをストレートに聞く質問を新たに立てることをオススメします。他のサービスのことを聞くことは今の質問から大きく離れているため、別の質問になっています。

Comment: そうなんですか？APIkey自体は何かのサービスに使うものでその連携した際に何かAPIに関したサービスに加入しないとお金かかるのかなと思い色々調べてたのですが...